# Rearrange inside environment

Tags: macros, environments

This is somewhat hacky.
I'm ultimately trying to create an exam template that rearranges itself. But, I want a lot of flexibility and the randomizing exam packages that exist don't seem to work.

I'm stuck on something that I can't really figure out. I want to define two commands, `\before` and `\after` that switch places along with everything after them. So, something like this:

```
Hi there!
\begin{switcher}
\before Blah blah

Paragraphs make things hard. \lipsum \foo
\begin{itemize}\item A\item B\item etc.\end{itemize}

\after This should hopefully come first.

As well as this!
\end{switcher}
This is normal!
```

Should give the exact same result as something like this:

```
Hi there!
This should hopefully come first.

As well as this!

Blah blah

Paragraphs make things hard. \lipsum \foo
\begin{itemize}\item A\item B\item etc.\end{itemize}

This is normal!
```

Ideally, I want the flexibility to rearrange a list like scenario. But, I'm pretty sure I can figure it out myself if I know how to do this basic example. I'm just not sure where to start.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.SE! You can grab the contents (tokens) of an environment using the `environ` package. Then the contents is available as the replacement text of a `\BODY` macro. The puzzle is solved by calling a macro of yours (here called `\@myswitch`) defined with delimited arguments on the expansion of the `\BODY` macro.

Note that this can also be done with commands from the `xparse` package if you like `expl3`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter

% I only added the \par to match the output requested in the question.
\long\def\@myswitch#1\before#2\after#3\@nil{#1#3\par #2}

\NewEnviron{switcher}{%
  \expandafter\@myswitch\BODY\@nil
}

\makeatother

\newcommand*\foo{Bleh!}

\begin{document}

Hi there!
\begin{switcher}
\before Blah blah

Paragraphs make things hard. \lipsum[1-2] \foo
\begin{itemize}\item A\item B\item etc.\end{itemize}

\after This should hopefully come first.

As well as this!
\end{switcher}
This is normal!

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Roadmap for an `expl3` version than can handle an arbitrary number of parts

In case you want to handle an arbitrary number of parts and shuffle them, my suggestion would be to use `expl3` and `xparse`:

- grab the body of the environment using a `+b` argument specifier with `xparse`'s `\NewDocumentEnvironment` command;
- use `\seq_set_split:Nnn` to store all parts (separated by a common delimiter of your choice) into a sequence variable; the delimiter can be a token list, it doesn't have to be a single token;
- use `\seq_shuffle:N` to randomly shuffle the sequence populated in the previous step;
- use `\seq_use:Nn` (or a similar function such as `\seq_use:Nnnn`) to output the shuffled parts to the document stream.